# HTACCESS and other files corrupted when saved

Tags: html, .htaccess, config, corruption

For some reason when I open a working .htaccess file and save it without any actual changes
(eg. typing space followed by backspace so the content remains)
And then Saving that file and reuploading it, the htaccess file no longer works and throws up a bunch of 404 errors on nearly every page. This happened yesterday.

Today I try to modify a config file and it also seems to be corrupted in the same way.

However, when reuploading the original file which I never made any saves to, everything works fine again.

I've also tried modifying files through my hosts cpanel file manager resulting in the same problem on this config file.

EDIT: I've also confirmed that the files are all being uploaded with the same permission, which is 644
EDIT: These two occurrances happened two days in a row on different webhosts with two different projects. I've also modified some PHP files which did not cause problems though...

Comment: What are you editing them with?

Comment: Tried with Notepad, Notepad++, NetBeans and the cPanel's file manager

Comment: Maybe the text encoding is the problem, as suggested before. Should be *UTF-8 without BOM*.

Comment: Well, on my cpanel file manager i was able to choose encoding and it was set to UTF-8 :/

Comment: try uploading your files using binary format

Comment: The selection in cPanel doesn't affect the encoding of your files, except they are created and edited in file manager, I guess. If Yazmat suggestion does not solve the problem, search for an editor like *EditPad* to modify the encoding. It's free as far as I know. Maybe with one of the suggested here it's also possible. Don't know, though.